# Find total from groupby.size() command

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a line of code which produces a tabled count from a `groupby` command of two columns:

```
beat_pri = df_2011.groupby(['Beat', 'Priority']).size()
```

table produced:

```
Beat  Priority    Count
01X   1.0          394
      2.0         1816

02X   1.0          644
      2.0         1970

02Y   1.0          661

                  ...
```

What I am trying to do from this is create a new column `'Total'` which is the total count grouped by the `beat` column. For e.g.

```
Beat     Priority   Count  Total    
01X       1.0       394     2210
          2.0       1816

02X       1.0       644     2614
          2.0       1970

02Y       1.0       661     2970
          2.0       2309
        ...
```

What I have tried so far is:

```
beat_pri2011['Total'] = df_2011.groupby(['Beat']).size().to_frame('total')
```

However this produces:

```
Beat   Priority  Count  Total   
01X    1.0       394    NaN
       2.0       1816   NaN

02X    1.0       644    NaN
       2.0       1970   NaN

02Y    1.0       661    NaN
       2.0       2309   NaN

                    ...
```

Thanks in advance.

(I have re-typed this question to clear up any confusion it brought earlier on.)

Comment: please show an example of your `df_2011` dataframe and your expected output

Comment: No new column, that's not needed. However if you wish to put that in the answer so other people searching can see then by all means go ahead. I just wish to find the top 'x' of what was listed and print the results in the way that was by `beat_pri`

Comment: @jezrael - no they're not the top 2. It was just ordered that way when printed

Comment: @jezrael - please check my note in edit. Your answer is great however, when `idx `is printed it gives the top x of beats wanted. I wish to print the x amount wanted in the format of the original table - giving the counts (of what `beat_pri printed`). `beat_pri` is ordered by 'Beat' and not total.

Comment: @jezrael - is my edit more understandable?

Comment: Hi. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Comment: @jezrael - I've edited this again. I honestly don't know how else to put what I'm trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

I mis-understood your question earlier. What I understand from you recent edit is you want to sort the aggregates after groupby by total count.

Is the following what you wanted

```py
df = pd.DataFrame([('ST&SAN P...', '1.0', '06X', '1.0', 'PDOA', 'POSSIBLE DEAD PERSON'), ('ST&HANNAH ST', '1.0', '07X', '1.0', '415GS', '415 GUNSHOTS'), ('ST&MARKET ST', '1.0', '07X', '2.0', '415GS', '415 GUNSHOTS'), ('PRENTISS ST', '2.0', '06X', '2.0', '415GS', '415 GUNSHOTS'), ('AV&FOOTH...', '2.0', '07X', '1.0', '415GS', '415 GUNSHOTS')], columns=('Location', 'Area-Id', 'Beat', 'Priority', 'Type-Id', 'Incident Type Description'))
df2 = df.groupby(["Beat", "Priority"])[["Location"]].count() \
    .rename(dict(Location="Count"), axis=1).reset_index()

df2.merge(df2.groupby("Beat").sum(), on="Beat", suffixes=("", "_Total")) \
    .sort_values("Count_Total", ascending=False)
```

**Result**

```
    Beat    Priority    Count   Count_Total
2   07X 1.0 2   3
3   07X 2.0 1   3
0   06X 1.0 1   2
1   06X 2.0 1   2
```

Comment: What is going on here?

Comment: I mis-understood you question, I have edited now, is this what you want?

Comment: I've typed it up but have `SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument` - I think for `ascending=False`

Comment: It is running well for me, can you run it separately may be your other code is giving that error

Comment: Ok - I got it working and have gotten the top 5 values using `[:5]` at the end. But it is still presented as the final total and not priority 1 and 2 values - then total value.

Comment: try now, where did you use [:5]

Comment: No this isn't what I'm looking for. The extra columns are `Priority_count` and `Count_count`,with `Priority_count` only having the value "3.0" I don't get what that is.